# C++ unordered_map problem

Tags: c++, unordered-map

This time I'm able to show a complete code:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

bool mystrcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
        int i = 0;
        do {
                if(s1[i] != s2[i])
                        return false;
        } while(s1[i++] != '\0');
        return true;
}

struct eqstr
{
  bool operator()(const char* s1, const char* s2) const
  {
    return mystrcmp(s1, s2);
  }
};


int main(void) {
    char buffer[5] = {'h', 'e', 'd', 'e', '\0'};
    unordered_map<char *, int , hash<char *> , eqstr> int_from_symbols;
    int_from_symbols["hede"] = 1;
    int_from_symbols["hodo"] = 2;
    unordered_map<char *, int , hash<char *> , eqstr>::const_iterator it = int_from_symbols.find(buffer);
    eqstr myeq;
    if(myeq("hede",buffer))
        fprintf(stderr, "no problem here\n");
    if(it == int_from_symbols.end())
        fprintf(stderr, "dammit\n");
    else fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", int_from_symbols[buffer]);
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
no problem here
dammit
```

Any idea what's going on?

Thanks in advance,,
Onur

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `hash<char *>` does not do what you want.  It is not specialized to actually hash the 'string' but is simply returning the pointer as the hash.

Add this to your code and it will start working (although the hash function is not production quality and is for demonstration only):

```
namespace std
{
    template<>
    struct hash<char *> : public std::unary_function<char *, size_t>
    {
        size_t operator()(char* str) const
        { 
            size_t h = 0;
            for (; *str; ++str)
                h += *str;
            return h;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I don't think that globally specializing `hash<char*>` for this is a good idea - among other things, this might make it very easy to break ODR. Why not just define a custom functor, and pass that as a template argument to `unordered_map`, as usual?

Comment: Check your <functional> header for the hash<string> specialization.

Comment: This is really annoying. I implemented other hash functions which encodes the structures as strings and used hash<char *> to hash those. Those hash functions worked correctly, if hash<char *> works incorrectly, why other ones worked correctly?

Comment: OK, you are right. hash<char *> barely returns the pointer. Thank you for the answer, however, I need a good quality hash function for strings. Can you recommend me one?

Comment: The namespace `std` is reserved. Never, ever drop anything of your own into it.

Comment: Technically I think you're allowed to specialise certain class in `std`, but this is wrong for another reason. `std::hash` should always match `std::equal_to`. Since `std::equal_to` compares pointers, `std::hash` must hash pointers. Doing otherwise will break `unordered_set<char*>`. Since the container is using a custom equality function, it should use a custom hash function to match.

Answer (score 1):

a review of a few hash function algoirthms for 'char *' here:

http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html

the sum of ascii codes mentioned above is not the best as the author of the comment says.